Variables substitution in sourceFileMap in launch.json in VSCode
If I use the following:
  "sourceFileMap": {
    "/app": "${workspaceFolder}/../"
  },

I have no problems, but if I use the following:
  "sourceFileMap": {
    "${input:remote_app_root}": "${workspaceFolder}/../"
  },

where:
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "remote_app_root",
      "type": "promptString",
      "description": "Application root folder in the remote",
      "default": "/app",
      "password": false
    }
  ]

then, I am not prompted for the input and the source file is not found.
It seems there is a problem with the variables substitutions. How to fix it?
